# Move sequentially through a date range

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, date

So I'm in a bit of a jam. I want to grab a bunch of data using SQL and list it on an Excel chart. However, I need to list it by date, like so:

```
   Date    |    Data
2015-05-19 |     62
2015-05-20 |     30
2015-05-21 |     78
```

Getting the data is easy enough, but I need to move through a date range (2015-05-19 to 2015-05-21, for example), listing every date I have and sorting data based on those dates. So if I have the date range as above, I need to sequentially move through each date in that range, and list the current value on my Excel sheet.

Anyone know how to do something like this? Sorry if it's not well explained, I'm not having an easy time with wrapping my head around it.

Comment: why not use the 'sort & filter' functionality in the home tab?

Answer (score 1):

This is using ADODB and an Access database so you may have to alter things to fit your needs.  It's all in the Sheet1 module.

```
Sub test()
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set cnn = getConnection() 'however you create a connection

    Set rs = cnn.Execute("SELECT YourDate, YourData FROM YourTable WHERE YourDate > #5/19/2015# AND YourDate < #5/21/2015# ORDER BY YourDate")

    Me.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs 'This doesn't include the fields names
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't actually what I was asking for. I posted the answer I came up with on my own actually, but thank you for answering anyways. I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an answer to this. Turns out that, should you add a number to a Date type value, it will be added as a day, allowing me cycle through my date range using a simple for loop:

```
For DateIndex = 0 To daterange
    'Add this date to the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Cells(DateIndex + 2, 1).Value = Format(CDate(CateringForm.DateCB.Value) + DateIndex, "mmmm, dd yyyy")
    For IDindex = 0 To IDNumber - 1
        tempdate = CDate(CateringForm.DateCB.Value) + DateIndex
        If (IDArray(IDindex, 3) = tempdate) Then
            'MsgBox "Match"
        End If
    Next
Next
```

This is what I came up with, and it's working well.